# Is it possible for a component to know where it was "implemented" vs "rendered"

Tags: reactjs, react-context, use-context

In the following code, I would like for the `PrintContext` component to print the context of where it was "implemented", which is different than where it is ultimately "rendered". Take notice of the `*Wants to be "app"` text in the code below - the `PrintContext` component is *implemented* inside of the `App` component, but is ultimately *rendered* as a child of `Parent` (and thus within a different context). Is it possible for a component to know where it was implemented?

> **NOTE:** I completely understand why it works the way it does - I'm just curious if there's any way to distinguish between where a component is implemented vs where it finally renders.

**UPDATE:** I have realized that the only real solution to this would involve the ability to pass a component to a function which would return the same component, but certain descendants decorated with new props. Does anybody know if this is even possible?

Here's a pen: https://codepen.io/DesignByOnyx/pen/MWbRjBy

```
const MyContext = React.createContext('asdf')

const PrintContext = () => {
  const ctx = React.useContext(MyContext)
  return <>{ctx}<br /></>
}

const Child = () => {
  return (
    <MyContext.Provider value="child">
      Should be "child": <PrintContext />
    </MyContext.Provider>
  )
}

const Parent = (props) => {
  return (
    <MyContext.Provider value="parent">
      <Child />
      Should be "parent": <PrintContext />
      {props.children}
    </MyContext.Provider>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <MyContext.Provider value="app">
      <Parent>
        *Wants to be "app": <PrintContext />
      </Parent>
      Should be "app": <PrintContext />
    </MyContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Comment: My instinct is to say this is just not how context works, but it's an interesting question.  If there is any way to do this it would probably have to be with some crazy manipulation of `React.children` to change the behavior.

Comment: Thanks @LindaPaiste - yeah, the way it works is nice and generally what you want. A  solution to this would involve passing the `App` component to a function which would crawl all the components rewrite the output such that every `<PrintContext />` had a new special prop such as `__context`. But I'm not having any luck doing that either...

Answer (score 1):

If you squint a little, would you agree that the way you have wired your contexts looks like a prototype chain?

```
class App {};
App.prototype.ctx = 'app';

class Parent extends App {};
Parent.prototype.ctx = 'parent';

class Child extends Parent {};
Child.prototype.ctx = 'child';

class WantsToBeApp extends Parent {};
class ShouldBeParent extends Parent {};
class ShouldBeChild extends Child {};
class ShouldBeApp extends App {};

const printContext = x => x.ctx

printContext( new WantsToBeApp() ); // parent
printContext( new ShouldBeParent() ); // parent
printContext( new ShouldBeChild() ); // child
printContext( new ShouldBeApp() ); // app
```

Ignore the direction dependencies are pointing. Doesn't it feel wrong to read "WantsToBeApp extends Parent" ? I mean if I met that component I would tell them that real beauty is on the inside ;) There is something impossible, inconsistent, with defining the relationships you define and not wanting them to be that way.

You didn't give a use case, so it's difficult to imagine why you would want to do this but obviously, if you need flexibility, you don't want to couple components like that. Everything is locked in place, one way by the parent/child relationship and the other way by the context binding.

Comment: That's certainly a way to visualize the problem a little differently. And you prove the point that it works as intended - which is not the issue. My use case is difficult to describe which is why I tried to reduce it down the the "problem" the best I could. fwiw: I'm trying to create "slots" behavior for react, and I need to know when a `Slot` component was "implemented" inside a component vs "rendered" inside another. The difference is important because the Slot belongs to the component in which it was implemented, not the one in which it rendered.

Comment: I never did something like that but can't you just pass the context provider as an argument to a higher order function then? The same way one would use `bind` to specify `this`. What I tried ton convey in my answer is that if there was a way to make `class X extends Y {};` ignore `Y` in the prototype chain, you would burn the fingers of anyone using it in your codebase. There must be some other way that is more explicit.